# How to setup Order By so that null rows will order based off a later constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  frst.FirstActionPath, scnd.SecondActionPath, frst.FirstIterationId, scnd.SecondIterationId, 
        frst.FirstTestRunId, scnd.SecondTestRunId, frst.FirstOrderId, scnd.SecondOrderId
FROM    @FirstRunData frst 
        FULL JOIN @SecondRunData scnd 
            ON frst.FirstIterationId = scnd.SecondIterationId
            AND frst.FirstActionPath = scnd.SecondActionPath

ORDER BY scnd.SecondIterationId, scnd.SecondOrderId, frst.FirstIterationID, frst.FirstOrderId
```

It gives me the following results:

[image: Results]

The top row is a row that is in the @FirstRunData table but has not matching row in the @SecondRunData row.

How can I change my order by so that the extra row will be after the row with the 10000 value in FirstOrderId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to take advantage of COALESCE in your ORDER BY clause.  For example,

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(scnd.SecondIterationId, frst.FirstIterationID, 9999),
COALESCE(scnd.SecondOrderId, frst.FirstOrderId, 9999),
frst.FirstIterationID, frst.FirstOrderId
```

Something like this my address your example, but you'll need to alter it based on your requirements for all conditions.